# Debug Error! abort() has been called

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Возникает ошибка при запуске кода в visual studio, а именно debug error abort() has been called, что в этом коде не так? Этот код это проверка числа на палиндром.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Palindrome(int number);

int main() {
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    Palindrome(number);

    return 0;
}

void Palindrome(int number) {
    string str1 = to_string(number);
    string str2 = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        str2 += str1[str1.length() - i];
    }
    str2 += str1[0];

    int number1 = stoi(str1);
    int number2 = stoi(str2);

    if (number1 == number2) {
        cout << "It's a palindrome";
    }
    else {
        cout << "It isn't a palindrome";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, чего стоит, например, ваше `str1[str1.length() - i]`...
При `i==0`, с которого начинается цикл, вы добавляете к пустой строке `str2` нулевой символ, тем самым делая `str2` в результате пустой строкой.

Для которой `stoi` бросает исключение, которое вы не ловите...

Но скажите пожалуйста, зачем? Нет, даже вот так: ***ЗАЧЕМ???*** вы делаете такую массу ненужных преобразований? Почему не просто работать со строкой изначально, не создавая никакую дополнительную, а просто сравнивая символы, в цикле идя с концов?